# Is there a delegate of unit -> unit defined in the standard library somewhere?

Tags: f#

For the sake of asynchronous error handling I need to add a callback to a Cuda stream. I have a function which looks like this that I need to rewrite in [Spiral](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) which compiles to F#.

```
type unit_to_unit_delegate = delegate of unit -> unit
let add_callback_to_stream (str : CudaStream) (callback : unit -> unit) =
    let callb (str : CUstream) (res : CUResult) (p : nativeint) =
        let t : unit_to_unit_delegate = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(p)
        t.Invoke()

    let aux = new unit_to_unit_delegate (callback)
    let ptr_to_aux = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate aux

    let cuda_callback = CUstreamCallback(callb)
    str.AddCallback(cuda_callback,ptr_to_aux,CUStreamAddCallbackFlags.None)
```

That first line is the one that is giving me trouble. I do not have a way to explicitly declare a delegate type in Spiral like in F#. I usually use macros for interop, but they are failing me here.

If it is not defined in a library somewhere I might need to hack the code generator to print out `type unit_to_unit_delegate = delegate of unit -> unit` at the start of compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a family of generic .NET delegates `System.Action` and `System.Func` that might fit your needs. Those are defined by .NET, so they use `void` rather than `unit`. Depending on your use case, that might be fine, but if you are doing something more tricky, it might be a problem. Given an F# function `callback` of type `unit -> unit`, you can use:

- `System.Action` is a delegate with no arguments returning void. F# can convert `callback` to this delegate automatically using `new System.Action(callback)`
- `System.Action<T>` is a delegate taking one argument of type `T` and returning `void`. F# can convert `callback` to this type too: `new System.Action<unit>(callback)`
- `System.Func<T, R>` is a delegate taking `T` and returning `R`. Again, you can use
  `new System.Func<unit, unit>(callback)` to get a `Func<unit, unit>` value

I'd start with the first one, unless you explicitly need delegate that gets compiled to .NET code taking and returning `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit`.

Comment: As it turns out, the Cuda callbacks do not allow memory transfers to host which makes them useless for my particular use case. I won't be pursuing this avenue anymore, but thank you for the reply.